# How to pass URIs as variable in BQ stored procedure

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-upload, error-handling, google-cloud-storage, bq

I am new to BQ and trying to load table via file from GCS bucket and getting error for uris .

**Query error: Found unsupported function call 'ARRAY[...]'; failed to set 'uris' in OPTIONS()**

**Code Snippet :**

```
begin
declare filename STRING;
declare SourceDir STRING  ;
declare infilename STRING ;

set SourceDir='dir/';
set infilename='file.csv';
set filename = CONCAT('gs://mybucket/' , SourceDir,infilename);

LOAD DATA INTO `dataset.tablename`
FROM FILES(
format='CSV',
uris = [filename]
);
end
```

I am getting the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach using [EXECUTE IMMEDIATE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) to pass `filename` as a parameter to your `LOAD DATA` clause:

```sql
begin
declare filename STRING;
declare SourceDir STRING;
declare infilename STRING;

set SourceDir='dir/';
set infilename='test.csv';
set filename = CONCAT("'",CONCAT('gs://mybucket/' , SourceDir,infilename),"'");

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
LOAD DATA INTO `dataset.tablename`
FROM FILES(
  format='CSV',
  uris = [%s]
  );
""",filename);
end
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!, I am able to successfully get filename in uris but my load is still Failing :   Unable to parse external_data_config for CSV tabledef (table cev.cd.DE_bcc5ee3f-8066-4967-a937-5c58da03a98f_source). Errors: Invalid uri in load data options..                                     but same file I am able to parse If filename is hardcoded . Please assist !

Comment: @Mudgal what is the value of your `filename` variable?

Comment: LOAD DATA INTO `dataset.tablename` FROM FILES( format='CSV',  uris = [' gs://<bucketname>/test_dacom.csv'] )

Comment: filename :
' gs://<bucketname>/test_dacom.csv'

Comment: This is working now @Ricco D , thanks for your help .           I just added single codes to  uris -> uris = ['%s'] and remove one CONCAT                                                     set filename  =  CONCAT('gs://mybucket/', SourceDir , infilename );

Comment: @Mudgal You can consider accepting the answer to mark it as solved. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)